# subprocess.Popen vs os.system; ssh command with interaction

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a script to perform a task on a remote server. There is a variable called `foo` that the command is stored in. That is represented below.

```
foo = "ssh -t -p 200 username@remoteserver -C -Y "sudo <any command that requires sudo>"
```

**The Probem**

When running `os.system(foo)` I am able to get a response back from the server asking for the sudo password. This is perfect, however I know using os.system is **out** and subprocess is **in**.

So I tried to switch to subprocess and when running:

```
subprocess.Popen(foo, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
```

I am not getting a response back from the server asking for my sudo password. So eventually, I break out because it will not work.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? I have looked everywhere and believe that `communicate()` has to be used however I am really confused on how that works.

Comment: I am still very much looking for an answer to my problem....